# GenerateOfficeAddInManifest task error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, add-in

I am using VS2010 to create an Office addin (for Outlook) and im getting the folowing error:

The "GenerateOfficeAddInManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "TargetFramework"

I don't even added code to my addin. Just created the template and build!

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem here? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I did... but I dont remember what... I think I have edited the project file and added the parameter "TargetFramework" to the "GenerateOfficeAddInManifest" manually.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to this project anymore but what I did back then was editing the project file and adding a "TargetFramework" to the "GenerateOfficeAddInManifest" manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. My solution was to install **Visual Studio Sp1**, and it worked like a charm.

If you guys are facing this problem, try to do the same before posting anything.